# How to concat, find duplicates and display result after joining mulitple tables(9-10)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, duplicates, concatenation

I want to concat one column each from multiple tables , after concatenation find if there are duplicates in the concatenation , display duplicates with a ID column from one of first tables.

I am able to do this but query which I have done looks very long and is bad from a performance perspective.

Here is the logic which is working -

```
SELECT ID , concatcolumn where concat column in (
(select concat 
join all tables
group by concatcolumn
having count(id)>1) a
JOIN
(select id, concat 
join all tables) b
on a.concatcolumn = b.concatcolumn )
```

This gives me what I want but I am no happy with it as
concatcolumn is a concatenation of 10 columns atleast , and wherever i have mentioned it will be replaced by that code.

Is there any other easier way ?

Comment: Your question needs a clarification. Sample data and expected output is a norm in SO.

Comment: Always send Schema, sample data and the result you expect can make your question more clear.

Comment: Your query is not even valid SQL syntax (it is missing `from` clauses).  This question makes no sense at all.